# Выравнивание таблицы

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Есть вопрос про таблицу:

Как мы видим, с ячейками в верхней части всё нормально. В нижней - левый столбец меньше правого. Можно как-нибудь отцентрировать оба нижних столбца, чтобы их ширина была одинакова? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В бородатых 2000х это делалось созданием внутри ячейки таблицы еще одной таблицы.
Накидал кодпен
http://codepen.io/klon_008/pen/yOzrRM

```
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">
        <table class="as">
          <tr>
            <td >aaa</td>
            <td >bbb</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Столько воды утекло с 2000-х, а таблицы всё ещё здравствуют!